# Can I reduce MySQL memory usage, or do I need to add more RAM?

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration, my.cnf, centos

I have a VPS with 2.25GB of RAM. MySQL is using 1.4GB with only four users on my site right now. It seems to use this amount even when no users are online. The available memory of my server regularly dips below 100MB, which is disturbing.

Yesterday MySQL kept crashing with OOM errors and resulted in database corruption, so that's what really prompted me to look into this issue.

I'm using the following configuration generated by the Percona Configuration Wizard (slightly modified):

```
# Generated by Percona Configuration Wizard (http://tools.percona.com/) version REL5_20120208
# MODIFIED SLIGHTLY

[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"

[mysqld]
slow-query-log=1
long-query-time=1

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
pid_file                       = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid"

# MyISAM #
key_buffer_size                = 32M
myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 256M     # Percona said 16M, but I need it larger to avoid errors
max_connect_errors             = 1000000

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = "/var/lib/mysql/"

######### removed the following because the logs were taking up TONS Of space:
# BINARY LOGGING #
#log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_bin
#expire_logs_days               = 14
#sync_binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 32M
max_heap_table_size            = 32M
query_cache_type               = 0 # was previously 1
query_cache_size               = 0 # was previously 32M
max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535 # was previously 4822
table_definition_cache         = 1024
table_open_cache               = 2048 # was previously 1024

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 128M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 1456M

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = "/var/lib/mysql/mysql_error.log"
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
```

As you can see, I increased `max_allowed_packet`, `open_files_limit`, and `table_open_cache`. I made the changes because I was receiving errors (I forget exactly what was causing them now) and making these changes caused the errors to go away.

Also, I noticed the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting is close to how much RAM MySQL is using (which may just be a coincidence), but as [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27341/31417) suggested I ran the following:

```
SELECT CEILING(Total_InnoDB_Bytes*1.6/POWER(1024,3)) RIBPS FROM
(SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Bytes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;
```

And the output was `2`, which I believe means the recommended `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 2GB. If that's correct, then my current setting is even below the recommended amount.

I really don't know what I'm doing and would prefer not to screw things up by blindly making changes to `my.cnf`. Are there changes I can make to reduce memory usage, or do I just need to upgrade my VPS plan?

Comment: If performance is ok, don't worry.  Don't let the server swap; MySQL will become seriously slow.  innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1456M is dangerously high for that small RAM; lower it.

Comment: @RickJames Since mysqld is being killed with OOM errors, I would have to say performance is not ok :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking the calculation of the recommended buffer pool size above is not correct. It assumes InnoDB works actively with *all* data. In practice, InnoDB could only touch a fraction of the database.

Check how `Innodb_buffer_pool_reads` and `Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests` changes over time.

```
mysqladmin -r -i 1 ext | grep -e Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests -e Innodb_buffer_pool_reads
```

if `Innodb_buffer_pool_reads` doesn't change much then all working set (a part of the database InnoDB actively works with) fits in the buffer pool.

Ideally the buffer pool should be as large so `Innodb_buffer_pool_reads` per second is zero.

You can make the buffer pool smaller, then some reads will be served from the disk, not from the memory.