# MySQL query very slow for one object, very fast for others

Tags: mysql

I have a table for `Items` and then a table for `Parameters` where each `Item` can have multiple `Parameters`. Each `Parameter` object has a foreign key back to its `Item`. I also have a `Parameter Type` table that stores the possible types of `Parameters`.

Here is the table info for my `Parameter` table:

```
CREATE TABLE 'parameter' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'type_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'value' longtext NOT NULL,
  'item_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  KEY 'parameter_403d8ff3' ('type_id'),
  KEY 'parameter_0a47aae8' ('item_id'),
  CONSTRAINT 'item_id_refs_id_eeb3b028' FOREIGN KEY ('item_id') REFERENCES 'tracker_item' ('id'),
  CONSTRAINT 'type_id_refs_id_53b2638a' FOREIGN KEY ('type_id') REFERENCES 'parametertype' ('id'),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31445609 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here is my `Parameter Type` table:

```
CREATE TABLE 'parametertype' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'name' varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'name' ('name'),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=309 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have two `Items`, IDs 115711 and 116792, for which I want to do this query:

```
SELECT p.`id`,
       p.`type_id`,
       p.`value`,
       p.`item_id`,
       p.`upload_id`,
       p.`creator_id`,
       p.`date_recorded`,
       p.`date_last_modified`,
       p.`date_added`
FROM parameter p
INNER JOIN parametertype pt ON p.`type_id` = pt.`id`
WHERE p.`item_id` = <ITEM_ID> 
  AND pt.`name` LIKE 'some_name' 
ORDER BY p.`date_recorded` DESC
```

When I do this for Item 116792, it takes 5.7ms. When I do it for Item 115711, it takes 9 SECONDS. The EXPLAIN of each query is the same except for the "ref" column -- for the fast query, it shows `const` in that column for the `parameter` table entry, where as for the slow query, it shows `parametertype.id`. Also, in the key column. The slow query shows data_parameter_403d8ff3 there (the key for the Parameter Type table) whereas the fast query shows data_parameter_0a47aae8 there (the key for the Item table).

What does this mean and why is one so slow? Is there anything I can do to make it as fast as the other query?

For context, Item 116792 has 560 `Parameter` entries and Item 115711 has 823 `Parameter` entries. The `Parameter Type` table has 237 entries.

The full EXPLAIN query for Item 116792:

```
    +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys                                   | key                     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                                     |
    +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | parametertype      | range | PRIMARY,name                                    | name                    | 182     | NULL  |    1 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | parameter          | ref   | parameter_403d8ff3,parameter_0a47aae8           | parameter_0a47aae8      | 4       | const |  559 | Using where                                               |
    +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The full EXPLAIN query for Item 115711:

```
    +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys                                   | key                     | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                                                     |
    +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | parametertype      | range | PRIMARY,name                                    | name                    | 182     | NULL                          |    1 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | parameter          | ref   | parameter_403d8ff3,parameter_0a47aae8           | parameter_403d8ff3      | 4       | parametertype.id              |  676 | Using where                                               |
    +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Did you try running the query with and without cache? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't seem to affect it

Comment: It was just to get a better idea of the true time each query takes

Comment: You might also want to check your innodb configuration, if you haven't done so already. Doesn't help with your query, but might speed things up globally. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size/27341#27341

Comment: Are you really sure pan from EXPLAIN is the same? Aren't the rows swapped or something? For the optimizer to use `parametertype.id` it has to know it, so read pt first, the other plan seems to use the const from the query itself. You can try `EXPLAIN EXTENDED <query>; SHOW WARNINGS;` too to see a bit more.

Comment: Apologies, there is one other difference -- in the `key` column. The slow query shows `data_parameter_403d8ff3` there (the key for the `Parameter Type` table) whereas the fast query shows `data_parameter_0a47aae8` there (the key for the `Item` table. What does that mean? I don't see any row swapping, though

Comment: Seems like you have some unstable statistics and depending how many parameters there are for a given item and how many types of a given name, optimizer switches two different plans. You could try running ANALYZE TABLE, but on InnoDB it will probably not have a big effect. Do you need the `LIKE` for `pt.name` ? Do you use any wildcards? Maybe using `=` instead might help the optimizer to decide better.

Comment: Yeah I don't need the `LIKE`, and I can certainly refactor things so that I don't need it, but I was just wondering why it was like that... is there anyway to force a specific optimization plan?

Comment: You can hint with [USE/FORCE/IGNORE INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html) or you can add a multicolumn index which will be good enough for the optimizer to use always - give it an index to use for ORDER BY too - `(item_id, date_recorded)` on `parameter` table seems like a good choice - it can be used to skip a filesort so will have a big priority probably - try to add it and then test explains and times with and without it using USE/IGNORE.

Comment: Thanks @jkavalik -- looks like doing a USE on the existing Item index was enough to make the slow query speed up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE parameter ADD INDEX(item_id, date_recorded)
```

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both the slow and fast queries.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the description to include the full output of the EXPLAIN queries

Comment: Added the index and used "USE INDEX" and that appears to have worked! In fact, it appears that even if I just use the existing Item Index that it goes as fast as it should. Thanks!

Comment: @samskeller probably your query is selecting only a few rows so filesort is not slow - but this index is better and should work without the USE INDEX

Comment: Even faster might be `INDEX(item_id, type_id, date_recorded)` _or_ `INDEX(type_id, item_id, date_recorded)`