# Extremely slow requests on small innodb tables

Tags: mysql, drupal

The situation is the following. Two InnoDB tables, one has 2 records, another one - 281 - small ones, insert and update requests may last up to two (!) minutes. Dropped db, created again. The situation repeats in a couple of hours. The tables are  history and semaphore from Drupal Commerce (Drupal 7).

Innodb settings:

```
innodb_fast_shutdown = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1280M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 4M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 180
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The users.uid that read the node nid.',
  `nid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The node.nid that was read.',
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The Unix timestamp at which the read occurred.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`nid`),
  KEY `nid` (`nid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='A record of which users have read which...';

CREATE TABLE `semaphore` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique name.',
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A value for the semaphore.',
  `expire` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp with microseconds indicating when the semaphore should expire.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Table for holding semaphores, locks, flags, etc. that...';
```

Upd.

```
show processlist;
+------+---------------+---------------------+----------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id   | User          | Host                | db       | Command | Time | State    | Info                                                                                             | Progress |
+------+---------------+---------------------+----------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+                                                                                      |    0.000 |
| 7996 | myuser       | localhost           | mydb | Query   |  129 | updating | DELETE FROM semaphore
WHERE  (value = '584023605761bad5c4a925.89704284')        |    0.000 |
| 8003 | myuser       | localhost           | mydb | Query   |  112 | updating | UPDATE history SET timestamp='1466022629'
WHERE ( (uid = '1') AND (nid = '40') ) |    0.000 |                                                                          |    0.000 |
| 8018 | myuser       | localhost           | mydb | Query   |   53 | updating | DELETE FROM semaphore
WHERE  (value = '6705735415761bb221d33c0.93445495')       |    0.000 |
+------+---------------+---------------------+----------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Upd2.

```
explain  UPDATE history SET timestamp='1466022629' WHERE ( (uid = '1') AND (nid = '40') );
+------+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table                   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | history | range | PRIMARY,nid   | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

[Engine Inndb Status](http://pastebin.com/JFpBYNnU)

Comment: Hope this help :  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27341/89077

Comment: 4 instances for 1.2GB buffer pool seems excessive, 1 or 2 should be enough. `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` is set twice so probably the smaller value is used.

Comment: Post the query. EXPLAIN it if your version allows, otherwise EXPLAIN an equivalent SELECT same conditions and select the rows otherwise updated). Get `show full processlist;` and `show engine innodb status\G` during one such occurence.

Comment: Updated the description.
Just removed the innodb_additional_mem_pool_size that was pointing to 4M, nleft only for 20M, haven't seen that, thanks.
innodb_buffer_pool_instance set to 2.
Checking the results...

Comment: Found something about the similar problem: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1898204
Solution in here: https://groups.drupal.org/node/415883 .
Trying to apply their solution. Seems to be working by now.

Comment: Are these queries produced by Drupal or developers? The quoting of literals that should be integers doesn't make sense: `WHERE (uid = '1') AND (nid = '40')`. Try changing that to: `WHERE (uid = 1) AND (nid = 40)`

Comment: These queries are produced by Drupal. For sure, I would not put number into quotes :)

Comment: @WindyWanderer your processlist probably does not contain everything - the status shows one transaction `TRANSACTION 3758562, ACTIVE 52 sec` currently probably "sleeping" but still holding `4158 row lock(s)` so it is quite probable the other statements just wait until it commits or otherwise ends.

Comment: @jkavalik 5 Yes, the holding transactions were connected with table "semaphore", causing deadlocks

Comment: What version are you running?  How much RAM?  `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` should not matter -- it was deprecated in 5.6.3.

Comment: `uid` and `nid` are `INTs`; so quoting the numbers is not harmful.  (`VARCHAR` vs non-quoted numbers is another issue.)

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`?  Since those 3 queries have exceeded the 50-second default, have you raised the value?  Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be the following.

Table 'semaphore' (innodb) was locking *everything*.
Moving it from **innodb** to **memory** fixed the situation.

```
ALTER TABLE semaphore ENGINE = MEMORY;
ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD PRIMARY KEY (name, value) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD UNIQUE name (name) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP INDEX value;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD INDEX value (value) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP INDEX expire;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD INDEX expire (expire) USING BTREE;
```

Also there were some additional changes made:

```
SET SESSION tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED'
```